# Angular2 router query params - copied on refresh

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing

I have a problem with routing and query params in Angular2 beta 11.

I have implemented nested routing through three components. Basic URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/settings/administrative/
```

After adding a query param it seems to be correct and looks like here:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/settings/administrative/;company=1
```

The problem appears when user refreshes the page or copy and paste URL into another tab. Then URL shows in this way:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/settings/administrative;company=1/;company=1
```

The next refresh, causes URL to be:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/settings;company=1/administrative;company=1/;company=1
```

As you can see upon every refresh query params are rewritten to the parent state, what for me is an undesired behaviour. In my opinion they should appear only next to the route they are assigned to.

Going to the way of implementation. The root component of my application defines the following route to the `Dashboard`:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/dashboard/...',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    }
])
```

Then I have a `DashboardComponent` which has a following `RouteConfig`:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/settings/...',
        name: 'Settings',
        component: SettingsComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    }
])
```

Going further `SettingsComponent` defines child route `AdministrativeRoot` in this way:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/administrative/...',
        name: 'AdministrativeRoot',
        component: AdministrativeRootComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    }
])
```

`AdministrativeRootComponent` acts as a wrapper for all other routes, concerning administrative settings of the system and its `RouteConfig` is following:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Administrative',
        component: AdministrativeComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    }, {
        path: '/branch/:id',
        name: 'ManageBranch',
        component: ManageBranchComponent
    }, {
        path: '/reception/:id',
        name: 'ManageReception',
        component: ManageReceptionComponent
    }, {
        path: '/room/:id',
        name: 'ManageRoom',
        component: ManageRoomComponent
    }
])
```

Finally I am navigating to the `Administrative` route with query params using the following code:

```
this._router.navigate([
    'Administrative', {
        company: this._selectedCompanyId
    }
]);
```

What do you think about such a situation, did I make an error in implementation or maybe in your opinion it is a desired behaviour? Did you have a problem like this?

To be more specific my project is based on angular2-webpack-starter provided by AngularClass. Maybe the problem concerns webpack configuration?

I am fighting with this for a few days, so I will really appreciate your answers and maybe a solution.

---

**Edit: 25.03.2016**

I've posted simplified demo on plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/8qRa3YJ1AdPjfFyvzk3X?p=preview